# Error problem: TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vehicle-detection.py", line 51, in <module>
    R = [r for r in R if r[0] in ['car','bus']]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'


bname = basename(splitext(img_path)[0])

R, _ = detect(vehicle_net, vehicle_meta, img_path ,thresh=vehicle_threshold)

R = [r for r in R if r[0] in ['car','bus']]
```

Comment: Is `r` a list, string, or a number?  The `r[0]` is probably causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

> __ getitem __

in a class allows its instances to use the [] (indexer) operators.
The list class is implementing it so we write code that looks like `num = my_lst[0]`
However it looks like you try to use the `[]` operator on a float number and not on a list.